# Can you nest fragments in GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, graphql-fragments

Say you have fragment B, which depends on fragment A. I wonder whether you can plug-and-play fragment B in a query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can!

Take these queries:

```
fragment Bar on Foo {
  bar {
    id
  }
}

fragment Baz on Foo {
  baz {
    id
  }
}


fragment MetaFoo on Foo {
  id
  ...Bar
  ...Baz
}

query Qux {
  foo {
    ...MetaFoo
  }
}
```

`Qux` is a valid GraphQL query.

Comment: What exactly is 'on'? is Foo a type? Like say I have Guild query, which inside provides an array of type Member called `members`. Would I then do something like `fragment memberList on Members`?